# Manhwa involving a girl with golden/yellow eyes

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers

The female was wearing a type of cloth over her eyes like a blindfold, and I think so did the male lead. I believe the girl has powers since it seemed like they were abusing it. It was a manhwa with color and the male lead came to rescue her, I think maybe in a carriage.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the girl? Also, I'm not sure what you meant by the second half of this sentence: _"The female was wearing some type of cloth over her eyes, **so was the possible the main character.**"_ Did you mean that the girl was possibly the main character, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, but it still isn't clear what you mean by this part: _"so was the possible the male lead."_ Do you mean that the male lead was possibly wearing a blindfold as well? Or something else?

Comment: yes the male lead was also wearing a blindfold as well when he came to rescue her, he had guards like around him with swords

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[The Isolated King and the Imprisoned Princess](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/whg6h3g/kokou-no-ou-wa-toraware-no-hime-kara-ai-oshiru)***...?

> Born to be a princess, Fine was raised in a tower with a blindfold on because of her golden eyes, which are said to be unlucky. Though she believed her parents loved her, it all turned out to be a lie when her father decides to offer her to the god to end the kingdom's long-standing drought. But right before Fine is pushed into the spring, the king of the powerful kingdom Stichtite, Sieghart rescues her. "I want to make Fine my wife." Fine is utterly confused by both the relief of having her life saved and his sudden request. Why did he save Fine and ask her to marry him when they've never met? Will Fine be able to find out Sieghart's true goal?

In the Kingdom of Rubellite, golden eyes are thought to be cursed, so when Princess Fine was born with golden eyes, she was forced to wear a blindfold and kept away from the public in order to hide this fact. Her parents regarded her as a 'monster' who might bring disaster to the kingdom.

When she reaches adulthood, her father decides to offer her as a sacrifice to their god in hopes of ending a drought. They place her wrists and ankles in shackles and plan to throw her in a spring and let her drown. However, just as she's being pushed in, a young man shows up and catches her.

This man is King Sieghart of Stichtite, the strongest kingdom on the continent, and he threatens to cut all ties with Rubellite if they don't spare Fine's life. He also asks for her hand in marriage, after receiving her father's permission, takes her away to his kingdom and removes her blindfold.

[image: The Isolated King and the Imprisoned Princess, chapter 2, pages 2, 3 and 4.]

Comment: I believe it is. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @IDK - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.